# C++ what purpose do __glibcxx* function calls serve?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, stl

In the implementation files for the C++ STL I see a lot of functions like `__glibcxx_class_requires` and `__glibcxx_requires_nonempty`.  What do these type of functions do? Should I be including these in my own files if I'm implementing a new Container that conforms to the STL standards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are actually not [functions, but macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261353/645128):

Information on these is scattered, but I did find some [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Libraries/), [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_macros.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118114/value-of-glibcxx-for-each-libstdc-release).

Mostly used for debug and are defined in debug.h.  Can also use for in-line asserts to prevent a program from continuing if certain conditions are met (not met).